# Java NullPointerException on HttpServletResponse line

Tags: java, servlets, nullpointerexception

Ok I am running the JSf application and I get an error of NullPointerException on line 220 which is

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```

not sure why would this be the issue. The full method in which the line is present is below:

```
    public void reserveDates(String eventTitle, Date startDate, 
        Date endDate, String requestType, int terminals,
        String lastName, String firstName, String middleInitials,
        int badgeNo, String networkID, String telephoneNo,
        String orgCode, String justification)
        throws ServletException, IOException{

    MapCreation mapCreate = new MapCreation(startDate, endDate);
    newMap = mapCreate.getDatesTreeMap();
    MapStorage mapStore = new MapStorage();
    mapStore.storeMap(newMap);
    //create instance of reservation class
     rsvObj = new Reservation(eventTitle, startDate, 
            endDate, requestType, terminals, lastName, firstName, 
            middleInitials, badgeNo, networkID, telephoneNo,
            orgCode, justification);
    boolean possible = rsvObj.checkRange();
    if(possible == true)
    {
        try{
        HttpServletResponse response = null;
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.sendRedirect("main");
        CreateTempStorage();
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.err.print(ioe);
        }
    }else if(possible == false){
        try{
        HttpServletResponse response = null;
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.sendRedirect("error");
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.err.print(ioe);
        }
    }

}
```

P.s.: The response giving the error is in the first condition where i check if(possible==true)

I am just trying to use response to redirect to the pages mentioned either "main" or "error"
I appreciate the support.
Thanks!

Comment: `HttpServletResponse response = null;
        response.setContentType("text/html");`

Answer (score 3):

you initialize response to null on the line immediately before the exception is thrown

Answer (score 3):

`response` is null at that point.  You set it to that right on the line before.

You need a concrete class that implements the abstract `HttpServletResponse`. If you have a class called `MyHttpServletResponse` that implements `HttpServletResponse`, then your code might look like this:

```
MyHttpServletResponse response = new MyHttpServletResponse();
```

(Perhaps you mean to use `HttpServletResponseWrapper` or something like that?)

Comment: Thanks for answering the question :D I will try this and hope it works

Comment: it doesn't. it gives that HttpServletResponse abstract cannot be instatiated

Comment: I've updated the answer but I'm afraid there would have to be more context to know what the actual solution is.

Comment: implement HttpServletResponse? I don't know how I could do that. Am new to servlets really. All I need is really just to redirect from one page to another. I use header() in php usually. any simpler mean?

Comment: Sorry, I know a thing here or there about Java but very little about servlets.  I do see that `HttpServletResponseWrapper` implements `HttpServletResponse` so maybe looking into that is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Where is `response` assigned a value?

Also, your code has "poor" style. Consider replacing this

```
if (possible == true) { 
    ...
else if (possible == false) { // there is no other possibility
    ...
}
```

with

```
if (possible) {
    ...
else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: its just a preference in coding style really but thanks anyway mate

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpServletResponse response = null;
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.sendRedirect("main");
```

You cannot call a method on an object after you set it to null. You shouldn't set the response to null. There should be a response object around somewhere. Pass it to your method.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is if you are writing this code inside the `servlet` then you will already have the `response` object otherwise if you writing this code in any `method` then pass the `response` object from `servlet` while calling the method. Actually we need not create an object of `HttpServletResponse`.

```
    try{
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        if(possible){
             response.sendRedirect("main");
             CreateTempStorage();
        }else{
             response.sendRedirect("error");
        }
    }catch(IOException ioe){
    System.err.print(ioe);
    }

A small improvement in code quality.
```

Comment: it highlights HttpServletResponse as abstract so cannot be instatiated...any ideas?

Comment: The thing is if you are writing this code inside the servlet then you will already have the response object otherwise if you writing this code in any method then pass the response object from servlet while calling the method. Actually we need not create an object of HttpServletResponse

Comment: another user seems to be using FacesContext instead for redirecting. Using that now and hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best option for an answer I believe was found in FacesContext. The code that replaced the redirection in this case was:

```
                    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                    ExternalContext ec = facesContext.getExternalContext();
                    ec.redirect("progress.xhtml");
```

Hope this helps others. Regards,